# How to convert String to Other type in Karate?

Tags: testing, automation, karate

My test is failing due to below assertion failure.

$.activeFrom | data types don't match (OTHER:STRING)
2023-04-28 00:00:00.0
'2023-04-28 00:00:00.0'
my requirement is to convert the string to other type so that assertion can be passed.
something like convert the  '2023-04-28 00:00:00.0' to  2023-04-28 00:00:00.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OTHER` typically means you got the value from Java interop, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+%22types+don%27t+match%22

I suggest you convert the `OTHER` to string, and one of these should work:

```
* string other = other
```

Or:

```
* def other = other.toString()
```

Make sure you read this also: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

Comment: * def other = other.toString() worked. Thank you!!!